# How can I correct Nginx reverse proxy for Tumblr using HttpSubsModule

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm working to make my site using my own domain with SSL/https(https://example.com) and show my Tumblr blog without the Tumblr URL(example.tumblr.com).

HttpSubsModule(Powered by Weibin Yao) has been added to Nginx, and /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy with the following :

```
server
{
listen 443;
server_name example.com;




ssl on;
ssl_certificate /root/example_com.crt; 
ssl_certificate_key /root/example.key; 
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;


location / {
subs_filter_types text/html text/css text/xml;
subs_filter example.tumblr.com example.com g;
proxy_redirect http://example.tumblr.com/ /;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host "example.tumblr.com";
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_pass http://example.tumblr.com;

}

}

server
{
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;


}
```

2 problem occurred:
① Chrome signed mixed content detected when loading https://example.com, 
② 404 not found when click any image.

Any idea what i am doing wrong here?Thanks a lot.

Comment: By using dotdeb.org's nginx with nginx-full.

Answer (score 0):

The website was able to work well along with the configuration as below:

```
server  {
listen 443 ssl spdy;
server_name example.org;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_org.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_org.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload;";

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
keepalive_timeout 70;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

location / {
subs_filter_types text/css text/xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml;
subs_filter 'example.tumblr.com' 'example.org' g;
subs_filter 'http:' 'https:' g;

proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host "example.tumblr.com";
proxy_pass         http://example.tumblr.com;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache cache_one;
proxy_cache_valid  200 304 3h;
proxy_cache_valid 301 1d;
proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
}

}

server  {
listen 80;
server_name example.org www.example.org;

location / {
return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
}

server {
listen       443;
server_name  www.example.org;
return       301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}


server {
listen       80;
server_name  178.60.000.00;
return       301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

In this case, be aware of the code `subs_filter 'http:' 'https:' g;`, which is the critical code for proxy reserve configuration successfully.